# Find packagenames online?

Tags: android, package

In my new app I am going to start other apps from my own app. But finding packagenames to all the apps is quite hard. I manage to make an app that finds the package name on all my current installed apps, but it would be much easier with some sort of online database or knowing where to look at the market.

Are there any online packagename databases, or do I have to find them out all by myself using my "packagename app"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to get info from other apps, you can use the code below. The code may contain some small errors, but it will give you a good starting point.

```
class PInfo {
private String appname = "";
private String pname = "";
private String versionName = "";
private int versionCode = 0;
private Drawable icon;
private void prettyPrint() {
    Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
}
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
final int max = apps.size();
for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
}
return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }
    PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
    newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
    newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
    newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
    newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
    res.add(newInfo);
}
return res; 
}
```

If you need to get access to system apps you can try to use the code below:

```
((packs.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) { continue; }
```

Why do you want to use a online database to retrive package name. Please tell me why you want to use a online database so I can post you some further information. 
If we look at the android market url(google play) we can see that it contain the package name in its url for the app. Example: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speaker.app` The id= is the package name. This may help you to understand where to look at the market as you wanted.

If you really need to have a online database: I would recommend using some sort of sql and requesting "info" from your app. This requier some server backend programming knowlegde.